# Celular não habilita Depuração USB

Tags: android

Comprei um "Galaxy On7" para teste de apps, porém, ao habilitar "Opções do Desenvolvedor" e ativá-lo, ao tocar na opção "Depuração USB", nada acontece!

Não ativa! No Prompt, ao dar o comando "adb devices", não aparece o dispositivo, mesmo pq, a chave não foi gerada, pois não está sendo possível 'ativar' a opção "Depuração USB".

Instalei no PC o Kies, o Kies3, o Smart Switch, depois, no dipositivo móvel, instalei o Smart Switch para mobile... Dei um kill no processo lá no Prompt, adb devices novamente, reiniciei o pc, reiniciei o dispositivo móvel.

"Revoguei Autorizações de depuração USB", nada!
Modo MTP ativado, nada!
Troquei o cabo USB, testei as portas USB do PC, do dispositivo móvel, nada!

Detalhe - consigo acesso aos dados do "On7" no PC - em  outros dispositivos móveis a depuração é ativada, mas no "On7", não! Uso o Eclipse Juno para desenvolver. Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Você tentou instalar o Google USB Driver?

Comment: já tentou instalar os drivers do adb? http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Comment: Olá, Vitor. O problema era no dispositivo móvel. Desinstalei o My Knox e resolveu o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Desinstala o My Knox No Samsung que a opção de depuração USB volta a funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Em aparelhos Samsung de fato tinha o Kies mas foi descontinuado e são aparelhos antigos, tente baixar o novo pacotes de drivers neste site: [gogorapid.com](http://www.gogorapid.com/download-samung-galaxy-usb-driver-for-all-phones/)
nele já encontrei os drivers do meu Tab S 10.5 para rodar uns comandos em `adb`, mas se não funcionar tente com [Driver Universal Samsung Usb](http://adbdriver.com/upload/samsung_android_usb_driver.exe)

Comment: Olá, iLeonardo. Pois é,  achei q o Kies3 resolveria. Então ao analisar o problema, com calma...  rsss... Percebi q algo no dispositivo móvel poderia estar impedindo a habilitação da "Depuração USB". E era o My Knox! Desinstalei ele e o problema foi resolvido. Obrigado pela ajuda e pelos links.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique o modo de transferência USB.

Tive um problema parecido com ADB, porque o meu celular estava na opção apenas "carregar" e não no modo de "transferência de arquivos"!

Comment: Olá, Bruno. Seria a transferência de arquivos em MTP? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

Obrigado, pessoal. Pelo q parece, o problema não está no Pc. O fato, é que não é possível habilitar a "Depuração USB", ou seja, qd tocado nessa opção, ela não é habilitada (o checkBox não é habilitado(selecionado))! A versão dele é "5.1.1". Independentemente dos drives, qd tocado na opção "Depuração USB", pelo menos o checkBox deveria estar selecionado, mas nada acontece! Vou tentar todas essas soluções que vcs enviaram. Depois posto aqui os resultados. Até breve.

Comment: Resolvido! Desinstalei o My Knox. Agora é possível habilitar a opção "Depuração USB". Obrigado pelos links pessoal... Serão muito úteis.